# PayPal express checkout integration

Tags: paypal

I'm sitting and digging in PayPal documentation but it is very unclear. I need to make server integration and in payment function of paypal.Button.render there is CREATE_PAYMEN_URL but I have no idea what should be in it? There are no php examples in PayPal docs.

Comment: Paypal documentation, developer samples and SDKs are [readily available](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/rest-sdks/)

Comment: I mean this https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/express-checkout/integration-jsv4/advanced-integration/ they don't say a word about SDK being required.

Comment: It's not "required". You can certainly write it from scratch if you prefer - the link above has source/samples that you can refer to based on the documented steps of the checkout flow.

Comment: The page you linked to explains the **Steps you need to do on your server**, which is what the `var CREATE_PAYMENT_URL = 'https://my-store.com/paypal/create-payment';` refers to.